# WooCommerce - Get the number of orders by a given customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to find that a particular customer has done business with that store previously.

To achieve that I need to find the number of orders by a given customer.

How can I achieve that?

I tried Googling, but did not find any solution.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Do you use php? (Maybe you should tag it with it.)

Comment: I looked at their API, but couldn't find a way to achieve my goal. Yes, WooCommerce is in PHP. Added the tag. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just drop in the user id and you'll get your total number of orders:

```
$numorders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $userid );
```

To go a step further for my own purposes, I use this code to get the number of a customer's *non-cancelled* orders since I don't want to count failed order attempts:

```
// Get TOTAL number of orders for customer
$numorders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $userid );

// Get CANCELLED orders for customer
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => $userid,
    'post_status' => 'cancelled',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'return' => 'ids',
);
$numorders_cancelled = 0;
$numorders_cancelled = count( wc_get_orders( $args ) ); // count the array of orders

// NON-CANCELLED equals TOTAL minus CANCELLED
$num_not_cancelled = $numorders - $numorders_cancelled;
```

Comment: its need add `'limit' => -1`

Answer (score 5):

Modifying @MarkPraschan Code, which works well for me without throwing any notice, as i got 2 notice about undefined variable $user_id and i'm not passing the code through a function. Using below code worked for me (which gets the number of order transaction minus canceled orders);

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$numorders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $current_user->ID );
// Get CANCELLED orders for customer
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_status' => 'cancelled',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'return' => 'ids',
);
$numorders_cancelled = 0;
$numorders_cancelled = count( wc_get_orders( $args ) ); // count the array of orders

// NON-CANCELLED equals TOTAL minus CANCELLED
$num_not_cancelled = $numorders - $numorders_cancelled;
```

if you intend to display both completed and non completed orders, you will use the first two line of the above code, which is;

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$numorders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $current_user->ID );
```

Tested and working on;
WP = v4.9.9
WC = v3.5.3

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd share my code/info anyways.

The customer will be connected to the order via the postmeta key `_customer_user` in the `wp_postmeta` table.

You can lookup all orders with the status completed and processing for a specific user ID with the following query, where `279` is the user ID:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON m.post_id = p.ID AND m.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND m.meta_value = 279
WHERE p.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing') AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
```

When translated into PHP code that can be used on any WP installation simply by placing the code at the bottom of your theme `functions.php` file.

This example displays the total orders for a customer on the order page in the back-end of WordPress, directly below the customer selection/dropdown. For instance if you need to know if this is the first order a customer has placed/done you can display a message. Obviously you will want to change the order status filter to something that suits your needs. Doing a direct query like below is more efficient I believe.

```
// Hook into the order back-end WooCommerce > Orders > [Edit]
// The output will be placed under the dropdown to choose/connect a customer to the order
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'f4d_customer_order_count');
function f4d_customer_order_count($order){
    global $wpdb;
    // Retrieve customer ID based on current order
    $customerId = $order->get_customer_id();
    // When the order was placed by a guest, just return
    if($customerId===0) return;
    // When the order is connected to a user/customer, query the total orders
    // Database tables we will use in our query (also grab the table prefix)
    $postsTable = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';
    $postsMetaTable = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
    // Filter orders by specific status
    $orderStatusFilter = array('wc-completed', 'wc-processing');
    // Connect the array into a string that is compatible with our query (IN() query statement)
    $orderStatusFilter = "'".implode("','", $orderStatusFilter)."'";
    // Only get the single variable from the database
    $totalOrders = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(p.ID) 
    FROM $postsTable AS p
    INNER JOIN $postsMetaTable AS m ON m.post_id = p.ID AND m.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND m.meta_value = $customerId 
    WHERE p.post_status IN ($orderStatusFilter) AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'");
    echo '<p class="form-field form-field-wide wc-customer-order-count">';
    if($totalOrders===1){
        // When this is the first order, display a message to our admin to give a first time offer
        echo '<span style="color:white;background-color:red;padding:20px;">FIRST TIME OFFER</span>';
    }else{
        // Otherwise just display the total orders the customer has placed in the past
        echo '<span>'.esc_html__( 'Total Orders', 'super-forms' ) . ': '.$totalOrders.'</span>';
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

If you need a list format of multiple customers/users, then you can use the `$wpdb->get_results()` instead of `$wpdb->get_var()` and loop over the results (table rows).

Answer (score -1):

Found a way.

```
$args = [
    'author' => 'id',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order'
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$orderCountByCustomer = $query->found_posts;
```